# selenium python how do i convert a string into time.strftime() date?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm reading a string from an html table that represents a date: Feb 1, 2024 87:05:23 AM. How do I convert this to a true date variable so that I can compare it to the current time?  Below is the code I'm using, it doesn't produce any errors but also is not working because when it gets to the compare it doesn't fall into the If statement.

```
#13. Start the recovery by pressing the "Start Recovery" button
try:
    logger.info("Step 13 Started: Start the recovery by pressing the 'Start Recovery' button.")
    currentTime = time.strftime("%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Start recovery")]'))).click()

    backup1_id = ''
    backup2_id = ''    
    tableRows = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="cdk-drop-list-10"]//tbody//following::tr')))
    for row in tableRows:
        backupTime = time.strftime(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.cdk-column-startTime').text)
        if backupTime <= currentTime:
            if backup1_id == '':
                backup1_id = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.cdk-column-id').text
                continue
            if backup1_id != '' and backup2_id == '':
                backup2_id = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.cdk-column-id').text
                break
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compare two strings directly.
Insted of `currentTime = time.strftime("%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")`
you should be using the datetime package, doing `from datetime import datetime`, and then in your code: `currentTime = datetime.now()` and later 
`backupTime = datetime.strptime(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.cdk-column-startTime').text,"%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")`

This compares the dates as datetime objects instead of strings, which are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'm not actually comparing dates!! :)